# Columns which are linearly dependent and every sub-columns are not

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, terminology

I am wondering if there is a name for the columns of a matrix that are linearly dependent but every subset of those columns is not. Any reference you know about this concept?

Comment: You could call such a set of columns a "minimal linearly dependent set"; that description is a bit deceptive, though.

Comment: I have a hunch that this is the kind of thing that might have a name in the context of Schubert calculus, so I'm adding the algebraic geometry tag

Comment: In a sense, this is the "most common" outcome.  For instance, among the $(n+1)\times n$ columns, the set of matrices whose columns have this property are "Zariski dense".

Comment: Thank you so much for this response. Actually I want to count this types of sets for a Toeplitz matrix. You have any reference on Zariski density or something like that which might help me?

Comment: I don't think a reference that defines "Zariski dense" is necessarily helpful for what you're trying to do.  If you could clarify what you mean by "count this types of sets for a Toeplitz matrix", I might be able to point you in the right direction.  Are you trying to find an algorithm that will give you all sets of the type you describe given a Toeplitz matrix?