# Counting the number of minimal linearly dependent sets

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-topology, independence, toeplitz-matrices

Let's define the minimal linearly dependent subset of a matrix as below

> Definition: For a matrix $A_{m\times n}=(\boldsymbol{c}_1, \ldots, \boldsymbol{c}_n)$ in which $\boldsymbol{c}_i$s are $m$-dimensional vectors, each set $\mathcal{S}=\{\boldsymbol{c}_{k_1}, \ldots, \boldsymbol{c}_{k_t}\}$ for a sequence $k_1, \ldots, k_t\in [0:n]$ is called a $t$-dimensional minimal linearly dependent subset of $A$, if vectors in $\mathcal{S}$ are linearly dependent but every $t-1$ members of $\mathcal{S}$ are linearly independent.

As an example, in the matrix
\begin{align}A=\left(
\begin{array}{c c c c}
a&0&0&b&0&0&0\\
0&a&0&0&b&0&0\\
0&0&a&0&0&b&0\\
0&0&0&a&0&0&b
 \end{array}\right)
\end{align}
we have $\mathcal{S}_1=\{\boldsymbol{c}_1, \boldsymbol{c}_4, \boldsymbol{c}_7\}$, $\mathcal{S}_2=\{\boldsymbol{c}_2, \boldsymbol{c}_4\}$, and $\mathcal{S}_3=\{\boldsymbol{c}_3, \boldsymbol{c}_6\}$ as $3$- and $2$-dimensional minimal subsets of $A$.

Upon my observation, for banded Toeplitz matrices, there should be some strong proportionality between the minimum dimension and the maximum number of total minimal linearly dependent subsets.

For example, as we see above, if we consider an $m\times (m+3)$ matrix formed by shifting $(a, 0, 0, b)$, there exists only 3 different subsets, each with dimension at least $\frac{m+2}{3}$. I guess there should be proportionality in the sense that, if we consider all types of banded Toeplitz, matrices, we have an increased number of higher-dimensional minimal subsets. What I like to prove is that the number is not that much, while the dimension grows.

Any idea on how can we find a tight relationship?

Comment: Your question could use some improvement, is not very clear. For example, I don't know what you even mean by a "linear subset" of a matrix. Take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on how to write a good question, and in particular [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) on how to provide some context including some basic definitions.

Comment: As I said in the comments on [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3578391/81360), the term "minimal linearly dependent subset" is deceptive, or at the least not clearly understandable without some context. You have also left out the word "dependent", making it even harder to understand what you mean.

Comment: A possible lead: Toeplitz matrices are often brought up in the context of "displacement rank"; there might be a helpful result from there.

Comment: If you reverse the order of your columns, then you have a Hankel matrix. Maybe the [Vandermonde factorization](https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~boley/publications/papers/HK97.pdf) of such a matrix is useful.

Comment: I suspect that there is "nothing special" about Toeplitz matrices, which means that generically (i.e. "in most cases"), every set of $r+1$ columns of a rank $r$ Toeplitz matrix will be a minimal linearly dependent set of columns.  If the matrix has $n$ columns, that comes out to $\binom{n}{r+1}$ such sets.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Now, would you take a look at the question? Does it make sense?

The link you provide for the Vandermonde factorization was very nice. I read it and used it in one of my problems. However, my main question still remained unsolved.

Comment: @AminCharoosaee The question makes a lot more sense now. One thing that you have neglected to mention explicitly is that you're interested in **partitioning** the columns of your matrix into minimal linearly dependent sets, or at least looking for a maximal number of **disjoint** minimal linearly dependent sets.  I maintain, however, that I don't think there's anything to take advantage of here in the general Toeplitz case; what you're taking advantage of in your example is the fact that there are a lot of zeros.

Comment: @AminCharoosaee Since you mention "using my link for one of your problems", it sounds like you're trying to establish the bound you're asking about in order to do a problem from a list of class/textbook exercises.  If so, then it probably makes more sense to ask about the original problem than it does to ask about this conjecture that you have come up with.  Unlike conjectures like this, exercises tend to have neat proofs or solutions.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm afraid that I don't want to partition the columns and count the sets. The main problem for me was "how many selections  of the columns spans a space in which there is another selection which spans the same?"(Let's call them S-selection) I figured that this case happens, only if in that selection of columns, we have at least $t-1$ members of a minimal linearly dependent subset of the matrix.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Hence, if for example each column are selected with some probability $\alpha$ and I want to bound the probability of S-selections, using union bound, it is only needed to kinda bound $\sum_{i=1}^N(\max\{\alpha, 1-\alpha\})^{t_i}$ which $N$ is the number of minimal linearly dependent subsets and $t_i$ is the dimension of each subset.

My conjecture is that this probability should tend to zero.

Actually, I am writing a paper on this stuff not solving classical problems.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You are totally correct about the number of zeros. But I'm afraid just considering sparsity without any kind of structure does not bring me to a lead for a reference.